# With RSA (n,d,e), can you guess the value of n, when it is not published; given some signed values: (V_i ^ e) % n

Tags: rsa

If you have an RSA keypair `(n,d,e)`, and you don't publish `n` to the world, how many bits of security is that?  For example, if I get a set of messages signed with the keypair, can I guess `n` ?

I have to consider this for a real practical problem. I am trying to replace the JWT scheme with something that is more fool-proof. I picked common tools: Sha256, RSA, and AESGCM for an implementation. I want it to be impossible for token signatures to be ignorable, and I want claims to only be decodable only to those that were given the (not entirely) public key `(n,e)`.

> In short, I am challenging common cryptography practice, that assumes that a signature of this form is safe: (plaintext,Sign(Hash(plaintext))

If you can present me with json claims, they have to be genuine, because you have to use the verification process to decrypt them.

first, the web token (not strictly JWT, but it is similar) is a tuple: `(keyId, encryptedClaims, Sig)`.

`V = xor( k, Hash(encryptedClaims) )`

`Sig = (V^d)%n` the signature is produced, because we posess the private key (n,d) and in practice, we also have the public key `(n,e)` because `e` is well known. We can choose to not distribute `n` to everyone.

`k` can be recovered by anybody with the (partially) public key `(n,e)`. Verify the signature, and xor with a hash of the ciphertext; to PROVE that you DID both of these things: `k = xor( ((Sig^e)%n)`, `Hash(encryptedClaims))`.

With `k`, we can decode the claims; and it serves as proof that we hashed the ciphertext and verified the signature. it is normally assumed that the public key of an RSA public key is broadcast to the world. But it looks like you can use the private key to give access to verifiers, without giving intermediate servers the right to decrypt the claims. Even though `e` is well known in protocol, you can give `n` only to legitimate verifiers.

This ends up using RSA as a pipe, where the owner of the private key can write into the pipe, and everyone with the public key can read from the pipe. With a scheme to generate a decrypt key from the verification process; we use RSA to make it impossible to extract claims about a user without verifying the claims. Compare this to a typical signature verification scheme, where the user is given the plaintext to hash BEFORE verification; in which case, we have no means of FORCING them to provide any kind of witness to following the protocol and verifying signatures. As a side-note, it seems impossible to force verifiers to look for a date in the claims (ie: `exp` field). But this fixes a loophole in JWT, where it is trivial to extract claims to make the signature check go away.

Note that for some of this functionality, I assume that you can't look at a bunch of `Sig` values and guess the value of `n`. That would be guessing `phi` `(p-1)(q-1)` from looking at a bunch of signed values.

Comment: Is it correct that adversaries know $e$, several tuples $(\text{Sig},\text{encryptedClaims})$, and try to find $n$? Do they know the related $k$? What's the width of $k$ and $\text{Hash}$? Is $k$ random for each signature?

Comment: so, I am only signing RSA hashes xored together.  So, it's 256 bit value `V` that is signed... so.    `Sig = (V^d)%n`.  `V` happens to be:  `xor(k, Hash(Ciphertext))`.  This is because I want proof that you actually did hash the ciphertext, and actually did check the signature. `k` is a witness to this, and it decrypts the ciphertext.

Comment: I have an implementation of this working in github.  The main questions are that whether this signature check allows for forgeries somehow (I don't see anything obviously wrong), and does it have the very nice property that only the signer, and verifiers can decrypt the claims.

Comment: `k` is a fresh randomly generated, per message, 256 bits.

Comment: `ciphertext = AES(k, plaintextclaims); plaintextclaims = AES(k, ciphertext)`

Comment: it's just an AES encrypt with a key `k`.  But crucially, the key isn't really secret.  It's a witness produced when you follow verification protocol.  `k = Xor(k, H(ciphertext), H(ciphertext))`.  But then I noticed that you need `(n,e)` to produce it; that would be a very nice property.  Only token signer, and verifier can retrieve claims. But can you guess `n` from sigs?

Comment: I am challenging the assumption that a signature of the form: `(plaintext, Sig(Hash(plaintext)))` is a good idea.  Web developers do immensely stupid stuff with JWT tokens.  `base64Decode(Split(token,".")[1])` indeed retrieves the JWT claims by not checking the signature.  But I want a format that says that if they managed to get the claims, they must have verified the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any signature $S$, if we know the associated value $V$ and we know that
$$S^e\equiv V\pmod N.$$
This tells us that $N|(S^e-V)$ where the number in brackets is typically a few hundred million bits in size, which is large, but not beyond the realm of general purpose computers. Given a few (two might be enough) pairs $(S_i,V_i)$, we can compute $\mathrm{GCD}(S_0^e-V_0,\ldots,S_m^e-V_m)$ which with overwhelming probability is a small multiple of $N$ (and for larger $m$ will just be $N$).

Comment: Actually, two pairs will almost always be enough

Comment: I remember now.  phi is involved, so you need access to the original primes.   `n = p*q`.  but `phi = (p-1)*(q-1)`.  So, you need to know the primes that were used to generate `(n,d,e)`, use `phi`.  The subtle point is that the modulus of the exponent is different from the modulus for the message: `M^((e' * d') % phi)%n`.

Comment: generate with well known `e'`: `(n, d', e')`.  `d = (d' + rand() * phi)`.  `e = (e' + rand() * phi)`.  `n=p*q`. `phi=(p-1)*(q-1)`.  I think that causes `(n,d,e)` to be such that both are equally private.  Sign with one, and verify with the other.